# Android Bluetooth Chat example - synchronized onPause()

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth, synchronization

Just getting into Android development. Have a fair bit of Java experience, including threads. I've been examining the BluetoothChat example and I'm puzzled to see that the onPause() and onResume() methods are synchronized. As both of these execute only on the UI thread, I don't see why this is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just because onPause() only runs on the main thead does not mean that other threads cannot be running at the same time.  This just ensures safe threading in case another thread is running and wants to access the variables that onPause() will be using/modifying.

It seems to me, the only thing this is preventing is if someone was trying to finish the activity before it was completely initialized (i.e. finished calling onResume()).  My guess is that it would prevent you or any other threads from finishing the activity before it gets to the running state.

Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755677/bluetoothchat-synchronized-onresume-activity-lifecycle-method-why).

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I don't think that holds. Synchronized methods prevent simultaneous invocation of more than one of the synchronized methods on a particular instance. onPause() and onResume() are the only synchronized methods in the Activity, and they will never be called in parallel because they're on the same thread. A non-synchronized method on the object could be called and modify a field used in a synchronized method (probably not a good idea, in general).

Comment: although, I think this is already how the activity life cycle works.

Comment: Nothing I've seen so far suggests that there can be contention between these two methods, though I agree this might be a way of tackling that eventuality.

Thanks for the link to the other question... at least I'm not on my own! (I did search before posting but didn't find that one).

Answer (score 0):

The android developer docs on [processes and threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) do a good job explaining how the app lifecycle works and where threads fit in.

Comment: I looked at that doc some time ago, but useful to refresh my understanding of Android in this area.... however, I don't see anything that helps answer my question.

Comment: I thought they were synchronized because of how the app lifecycle works. onPause and onResume cannot be called at the same time.

Comment: Are you suggesting that synchronization is being used to enforce that? I've not seen anything to suggest that's necessary. My understanding is that the system will not call onPause and onResume at the same time... the link given by Joel indicates others have had the same question as me.

Comment: That is what I am suggesting although you are right I cannot find anything specificlly addressing this issue either. It's good question. However, it does not seem to be addressed in any of the android documentation.